# How to consume output of a Task in luigi

Tags: python, luigi

I have two luigi tasks.

**TaskA** runs an external program and the results are stored as a json with `luigi.LocalTarget`

```py
    class TaskA(ExternalProgramTask):
        def output(self):
           return luigi.LocalTarget(self.outputfile)
```

In TaskB I want to do some transformation of the json and `pickle.dump()` it. But I have issues opening the file.

```py
@inherits(TaskA)
class TaskB(luigi.Task):
    def requires(self):
        args = {....}
        return TaskA(**args)

    def run(self):
        try: 
            entries = json.load(self.input().open())
        except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError as e:
            logging.error(f"Decoding error: {e}")
            return print(e)
```

But this is not working as I am getting a decoding error:

`Decoding error: Expecting value: line 6 column 1`

which makes sense, if I try to print `self.input().open()` I would expect the json. But instead I am getting: `<_io.TextIOWrapper name='task1.output.json' mode='rb' encoding='UTF-8'>`

I also tried to use `yield TaskA()` but this also did not work. But according to the documentation, it should work.

Using Python 3.8.1 and latest luigi version.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.

Indeed the decoding error makes sense. I was checking my input.json which was generated by an external tool, and it was a json.

However, the tool had a bug in it and appended a comma on the last entry, which made it an invalid json.